# twitter-bootstrap container should overlap another container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to let one container-fluid to overlap with a container. The second container should be positioned at the beginning of the first column. The container-fluid should be positioned at the edge of the browser screen.

I have tried so far with `position: absolute` and `position: relative`. Here is my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/768/

Anyone can help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To get your second container in your first, just add `top:0;` to your `.second` css.

```
 .second {
  background-color: #38A453;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```